# here is a theorem that the isometries of the Hyperbolic plane are generated by $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $z \rightarrow - \overline{z}$.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

There is a theorem that the isometries of the Hyperbolic plane are generated by $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $z \rightarrow - \overline{z}$.

My question is, isn't $z \rightarrow kz$ an isometry for $k>0$?  I don't see how it is generated by the set in question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \left( \begin{array}{rr}
     \sqrt k & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt k}
   \end{array}
   \right)
$$

Comment: Oh yea.  That was easy.

Comment: @kingkongdonutguy, not even necessary. PSL includes modding out by scalar multiples of the matrix. So, a positive determinant is all that is required. Note that negating all four entries keeps the same determinant and the same Mobius transformation. Multiplying by any nonzero scalar keeps the same Mobius transformation.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling map $z \mapsto kz$ for $k > 0$ can be identified with $\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{k} & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{k} \end{pmatrix} \in PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ because it acts by fractional linear transformation as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{k} & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{k} \end{pmatrix} z = \frac{\sqrt{k} z + 0}{0 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}} = k z.
$$